# JavaScript - addEventListener is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am creating a chrome extension for blocking ads. Everything worked pretty fine so far. My goal is to:

1. Disable `WebSocket`
2. Disable `console.log`
3. Disable `alert`
4. Disable popups (`window.open`)
5. Disable `onbeforeunload`

Of course, it is supposed to block these functions only on specified websites. I searched on how to block a function. What I found is that the only way to disable a function using extension is to

1. In `manifest.json` add a content script `init.js` which will run at `document_start` (this will prevent any other code from being executed before my extension's code, so nobody can steal and save reference to these functions before I disable them)
2. From `init.js` inject code in webpage, so that my extension can access non-sandboxed environment
3. Override blacklisted functions

I did everything, but the problem was how to override functions. I found on EcmaScript7 specification that **there is no way to detect if a function is proxy instance or not**. So, I proxyfied every of these functions and it works as expected. Websites couldn't notice that I've overriden all of these functions.

However, it works for all functions expect `addEventListener`. In order to block `onbeforeunload`, I should add a proxy handler to it and track calls to check if listener name is `onbeforeunload`. I wrote the following script:

```
addEventListener = new Proxy(addEventListener, {
  apply: (f, t, args) => {
    if(args[0] !== 'onbeforeunload'){
      f.apply(t, args);
    }
  }
});
```

This should filter calls and allow only calls which doesn't set `onbeforeunload` event. However, it throws **ReferenceError: addEventListener is not defined**. It surprised me a lot. I supposed that it is maybe because `addEventListener` is not yet initialized at `document_start`, but **console.log(typeof addEventListener)** logs `function` to console. How is that even possible?

I couldn't explain it. However, I tried to put it in a function and then to `requestAnimationFrame` to that function until `addEventListener` become accessible (I ecapsulated the above code in `try...catch` too). But, it turns out that modifying `addEventListener` **always throws ReferenceError**, while just accessing it **never throws error**.

I also tried to access it from developer console and from `javascript:...` method, but it behaves normally, I can modify it without any errors.

## Edit

For sure, the problem **isn't like** [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script), becuase **I properly injected script** into non-sandboxed (real) page environment and I have access to real `window` object.

Comment: Why do you want to disable sockets and console.log?

Comment: @DanielHerr. A lot of websites transfer ads as `image:data` through `WebSockets`. Standard `adBlock` will never be able to block them. So, i decided to create my own extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`addEventListener` isn't a global</s> Actually, it is, indirectly. It's a property of `EventTarget.prototype` (at least in Chrome). `window` has `EventTarget.prototype` in its prototype chain, which makes `addEventListener` a global.

So you'd need to proxy that instead, roughly (without your event name check, just for demonstration):

```js
const save = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = new Proxy(save, {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, args) {
    console.log("Foo!");
    return save.apply(thisArg, args);
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<p>....</p>
```

Other notes:

- The event name is `beforeunload`, not `onbeforeunload`.
- You'll need to redefine the `window.onbeforeunload` property to prevent assignments to it, probably via `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: I have no idea whether you'll run into issues doing that or whether your overall approach will work (good luck with it!), but that's why you were getting the error about `addEventListener`... :-)

Comment: Just one more question. How would you explain that modifying `addEventListener` throws a `ReferenceError` while it is defined and I can access it, but not modify it?

Comment: @jumpjet__ I'm not sure why you'd get that. I don't when I try it in a normal Chrome window. BTW, I wasn't thinking earlier, `addEventListener` *is* global, because `window` inherits it from `EventTarget.prototype`. :-) But assigning to `window`'s version wouldn't handle updating it everywhere.